# How to test error for a stream in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I have a function which create a md5 and I have created a test which check its behavior, the script works. Now I need to create a test which check the promise is rejected when `createHash()` or `createReadStream()` fails.
How to test this scenario, any best practices? I would appreciate if you could post a sample, thanks!

```
export const md5 = (path: string) =>
  new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    const hash = createHash("md5");
    const rs = createReadStream(path);
    rs.on("error", reject);
    rs.on("data", chunk => hash.update(chunk));
    rs.on("end", () => resolve(hash.digest("hex")));
  });
```

---

```
describe("md5", () => {
  const fileName = `${TEST_DIR}/file1.txt`;

  beforeAll(() => createFile(fileName));

  afterAll(() => removeFile(TEST_DIR));

  it("should hash md5 a file", () => {
    md5(fileName).then((hash: string) => {
      assert.strictEqual(hash, "4738e449ab0ae7c25505aab6e88750da");
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create a test which check the promise is rejected

Try the code below: the 2nd parameter of a Jasmine `it` block is a function that has a parameter `done` passed to it. `done` is a function that the user can invoke to make the test *pass*. If `done` is not invoked within the timeout window, Jasmine considers the test a *failure*.

**stream-reader.js**

```
const fs = require('fs')

const createReader = inputFile => {
  const reader = fs.createReadStream(inputFile, {encoding: 'utf8'})
  const result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reader.on('error', e => reject(e))
  })

  // return 2 things...
  return {
    reader,  // ...a stream that broadcasts chunks over time
    result,  // ...a Promise to be resolved on reading is done or error encountered
  }
}

module.exports = createReader
```

**spec.js**

```
const streamReader = require('../stream-reader')
const INPUT_FILE = './input1.txt'

describe('streamReader', () => {
    it(`should pass a chunk of the file on 'data' event`, (done) => {
        const api = streamReader(INPUT_FILE)
        api.reader.on('data', (chunk) => {
            console.log('[JASMINE TEST 1] received', chunk)
            done()
        })
    })

    /* test Promise.reject on stream error */
    it(`should reject on case of reading errors`, (done) => {
        const api = streamReader('./non/existent/file')
        api.result.catch(e => {
            console.log('[JASMINE TEST 2] correctly rejected')
            done()
        })
    })
})
```

**output**

```
$ npm test

> so-jasmine-test@1.0.0 test C:\Users\jonathanlopez\nodejs\so-stream-reject
> jasmine

Randomized with seed 22758
Started
[JASMINE TEST 1] received the quick brown fox
.[JASMINE TEST 2] correctly rejected
.


2 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 0.026 seconds
Randomized with seed 22758 (jasmine --random=true --seed=22758)
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could your md5 function for error in this way

```
md5('bad_path').catch((error: Error) => {
  assert.strictEqual(error.message.length > 0, true);
});
```